# What's the difference between Mellow Mode and Classic Mode?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, poochy-and-yoshis-woolly-world

When you start the game, it asks if you want to choose Mellow Mode, which says "this mode makes the game a little breezier and more relaxed", or Classic Mode, which says "this mode is recommended for more experienced players".

What are the actual gameplay differences between the two?

Answer (score 1):

In the demo of Yoshi's Wooly Word for the new 3ds xl, if you select melow mode, Yoshi grows wings and allows you to fly around the stage sort of like Kirby. This makes most levels extremely easy because you can just fly on the top of the screen for the entire level.

Comment: This provides no information different from the other answer given, which was shown to not help/give concrete information. If possible, provide some.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search showed me [this](http://www.polygon.com/2015/4/1/8325299/yoshis-woolly-world) thread with the following quote for mellow mode:

> The game's Mellow mode offers a kinder experience by allowing players to try "winged Yoshi," and soar through levels.

I reckon that this does not change the actual "difficulty" of the level, but rather includes a feature where Yoshi can "soar" - in other words, "cheat" your way past any difficult piece's in the game by simply flying past them.

Comment: Is this the same for the 3DS version? Did they add or change anything with the modes for this version?

Comment: Actually, I did play this on the 3DS but the image in the thread shows a wiiU, but that does not mean that their are not difference's..

Comment: the 3ds version just came out today, though.

Comment: How is that possible?

Comment: Let me research this.

Comment: Do you know of any older versions of yoshi on a wooly world?

Comment: I believe I must have played this > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshi's_Island_DS .

Comment: I do feel like I played a wooly game though. But i have never owned a wiiu